# How to use JQuery to load images with callback facility

Tags: jquery

i use this code to preload images.

```
var ImagePath='../images/pop.gif';
var _images = [ImagePath];
            $.each(_images, function (e) {
                $(new Image()).load(function () {
                }).attr('src', this);

            });
```

i want to attach a callback which will notify when image load completed in client machine. please guide me. thanks

### UPDATE

just see my below code. i just need to know can i write in this way to notify when each image loading will be completed.

```
$.each(_images, function (e) {
     $(new Image()).load(function () {
     // image load completed
     }).attr('src', this);
});
```

please guide. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood what you're asking for......

```
$(_images).on('load', function() {
    //images loaded
});
```

Comment: i was looking for manipulation in my code. so plzz have a look at my updated version.can i write in this way to notify when each image loading will be completed.

Comment: could you please create a fiddle so i can understand fully what you are trying to achieve